# "A failure may be iminent and cause unpredictable fail" error after dual booting Windows 11 + Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, dualboot

I was using Windows 11 and did a dual boot (via flash usb) in Ubuntu 22. For the first coupe days, everything went normal, but then every time I turn the PC on, the ["A failure may be iminent and cause unpredictable fail"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veYIW.jpg) message pops up and I get other warnings in both OS.

Everything leads me to think that it was the dual boot, but I'm not sure. I tried to delete the Ubuntu partition manually via Windows' Disk Manager, though the partition remains unchanged despite clicking on "Delete Volume" and wait.

Currently I can boot on both OS by BIOS, but Windows sometimes throws me a blue screen. Can you guys help me delete Ubuntu and, if possible, figure out what did I do wrong in the installation for this to occur?

Specs:

- Desktop, not notebook
- CPU: i5-10400F
- SSD: Hyperion AKTEK 2.5 240GB A400 SATA III
- GPU: GTX 1050
- OS: Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: The warning is about an imminent failure of the drive. It has nothing to do with with dual-booting and removing or reinstalling any of the OSes will change NOTHING. Replace the drive.

Answer (score 2):

Since the message states there's an issue with the hardware, i.e., the "hard drive: (or the flash USB drive, in this case), it's doubtful that it has anything to do with the OS, whether Windows or Linux.

That said, Windows *did* have an issue with [updates damaging an SSD's system](https://hothardware.com/news/windows-10-20h2-update-damages-ssd-file-systems-chkdsk), or even permanently [destroying the SSD itself](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/314335-fix-for-potential-ssd-damaging-bug-coming-in-windows-update).

The question is, is there damage to the relatively inexpensive, easily replaced flash USB drive, or to the internal Hyperion SSD? You can determine that by checking the [S.M.A.R.T. data](https://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/) in either Windows or in Ubuntu.

In either case, dual boot, whether installed on the SSD, or with a USB drive, is *not* the cause of the issue.